# React Lodash groupBy

Tags: reactjs, lodash

when i use `groupBy` with `lodash` i get `TypeError: Object(...)(...).map is not a function`. When I use `sortBy` I do not have such a problem. My goal is to make a list of questions. In the beginning I want show a picture with category, then list of questions.

```
const images = require.context('../../img', true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);

const QuestionsList = ({ questions }) => {


  const questionListItem = questions && questions.questions ?
    groupBy(questions.questions, ['type']).map((question) => (
      <>
        <img src={imagePath(`./${question.type}.png`)} alt="star" />
        <QuestionsListItem
          key={question.id}
          type={question.type}
          question={question}
        />
      </>
    )) : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { questionListItem }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: GroupBy returns an object, not an array.

Comment: You can map over Object.values(...), Object.keys(...) or Object.entries depending on whether you care about the key or not

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's groupBy returns an object, rather than array, which is why you can't map through it. You'll need to loop through the object properties and map the arrays held in those values.

```
for (let key in questions) {
  questions[key].map(q => (
        <>
           <img src={imagePath(`./${q.type}.png`)} alt="star" />
           <QuestionsListItem
              key={q.id}
              type={q.type}
              question={q}
           />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since lodah's [`groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) returns an object where each key is a one of your types, and the value is an array of items with that type, you can't iterate it with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

However, you can use lodash's [`map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map). You'll need one map to iterate the groups, and another to iterate the items inside. You can use [`flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) to wrap the operations.

Example (not tested):

```
const renderGroupupItems = flow([
  arr => groupBy(arr, ['type']),
  groups => map(groups, group => 
    map(group, question => (
      <>
        <img src={imagePath(`./${question.type}.png`)} alt="star" />
        <QuestionsListItem
          key={question.id}
          type={question.type}
          question={question}
        />
      </>
    )
  )
]);

const QuestionsList = ({ questions }) => {
  const questionListItem = has(questions, 'questions') ?
    renderGroupedItems(questions.questions) : null;

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { questionListItem }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```